# Google Sheets: How to keep links to ranges pointing at the current sheet after it has been copied?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with some links to ranges in a frozen pane to help navigate around. The sheet is a template for future duplicates to be made. When I make a duplicate the links point to the 'parent' sheet and not to the newly made one. Is there a simple way to make these links point to the newly created sheet automatically when the sheet is duplicated?

I created the links using the insert link (ctrl k) method (just linking to a cell) and have tried using named ranges but that didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies. I took a break, had a cup of tea and then came back to this and found a solution to my problem. I used a script to get the URL of my sheet then just concatenated that with the cell addresses to get links that update every time I copy the sheet.

Thanks to Max, here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/93305/how-to-find-url-of-the-current-sheet

Sorry for the time waste - maybe there's a better way...?

Answer (score 0):

When you say duplicated, do you mean:

- copied and pasted into a new workbook file
- duplicating the file using File > Make A Copy
- copying the cells and pasting in a new tab within the workbook

Based on your question, it seems that you are asking about copying and pasting within the same workbook. The Insert Link method treats the hyperlink as an absolute value, so it would still link to the original cell.

### Solution

To create relative hyperlinks you need to use the HYPERLINK() function.

```
    =HYPERLINK("[link to sheet]/edit#gid=0&range=" & SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",C2),"$", ""),  "Best Doctor")
```

1. Go to the cell that you want to link to > Right Click > Get link to this cell
2. In the cell with the link, use the HYPERLINK function and paste in the cell URL
3. Need to replace the absolute cell address in the link with a relative one, using CELL and SUBSTITUTE
4. CELL gets the absolute cell reference $C$2, but the link won't work with the '$', SUBSTITUTE strips those out.
5. Use '&' to concatenate the link up until 'range=' with the cell reference formula

Now, as long as the cells remain in the same relative positions, you can copy and paste them anywhere else in the workbook.

### Example

[Link to workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KFBRMXIWxSjudgXLSP6oHi0PHDXkkjlO6JPxZfNXsmw/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: Example tables with relative hyperlinks]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I mean copying the tab - right click the tab and click "duplicate". In my case this means I get a new copy of my "Template" tab called "Copy of Template" but the usual method of creating links to ranges within a sheet all point to the parent "Template" instead of "Copy of..." The below solution I adapted from the script to get sheet URL into a cell on the sheet then pointed the =HYPRELINK at that cell and CONCATENATE with "&range=" and the relative cell ref of the target.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a somewhat simple, and definitely ugly, kind of solution:

```
=HYPERLINK(**C47** & SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address";R1);"$"; "");  "Link")
```

Where the **C47** cell needs to be updated with the duplicated sheet name (link range).

eg. **C47** content: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X1L..../edit#gid=94945&range=`

**C47** could be any cell (and hidden).

Comment: Thank you, Majid. For fixing the formatting.